# Communication between Model and Controller

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, swift

After reading from many different sources, I am very confused about **how View and Model should communicate in the MVC with Swift**

How to do the same thing with Swift (here in objective-c)

**In the model:**

```
(void)receivedMessageFromServer {
    // Fire the notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedData" object:nil];   
}
```

**Handle the "ReceivedData" notification in View Controller(s):**

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedDataNotification:) name:@"ReceivedData" object:nil];
}

-(void)receivedDataNotification:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"Received Data!");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
func receivedMessageFromServer() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ReceivedData", object: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receivedDataNotification:", name: "ReceivedData", object: nil)
}

func receivedDataNotification(object: AnyObject) {
    println("Received Data!");
}
```

Comment: Omitting `-> ()` is even briefer.

Comment: with selector: "receivedDataNotification:"

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you can use the "didSet" closure in the property declaration to notify the viewController whenever the variable is changed.

In terms of how to do the notification, useing NSNotificationCenter (above answer) or delegation(protocol in the model, implement it in the viewController) will work.

Hope this helps.